# Input Form database styling

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I am trying to create form that user will use to add data to database here is example:

```
<form method="get" action="">
English Word: <input name='word'>
</form>
<?php
$word=$_GET['word'];
$sql="INSERT INTO engdic (`EnglishWord`) VALUES ('<li><b>$word</b></li>')";
?>
```

So the idea is costumer will input just plain text and threw php  it will add html tags to that text that will apply specific styling. What I am really looking is for good example or any idea how to do it correctly officient etc. 
I will have about 20 different another example field for url for video so instead of costumer adding link with html tagst etc. code , I want that costumer only add url and rest is added by js or php  . Sorry for my bad English and I hope the my idea is clear. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection.  Please take a look at mysql security: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Not only that but without javascript, your form is submitting to nothing. Nor have you declared an input type, or even closed the input tag correctly (it's not closed at all).

Comment: RUJordan sorry for confusion my question is not about syntax but about examples this is just idea what I need

Answer (score 1):

Save just the word in the database, style it right before you display it.

Comment: Yes. But remember to escape anything that goes into the database. The simplest way to escapse is to use mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it by creating one new variable and then save that variable.

```
$save = '<li><b>'.$word.'</b></li>';

INSERT INTO engdic (`EnglishWord`) VALUES ('$save')
```